# Why past simple has been used in the conditional?

Tags: grammar

Why is the if clause written in past tense instead of past perfect in this sentence?

> “they would have not done that if it was not safe”

Comment: Because it's still safe. So the condition applies to the present, even though the main clause only applies to the hypothetical past. They could equally well have used past perfect.

Comment: The sentence sounds clumsy, "would not have done that" seems to flow better.